# ethernet stopped working on ubuntu 14.04, still works on windows

Tags: networking, ethernet

Everything was working fine on my Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit installation (on a Dell Vostro laptop) yesterday. I shut it down last night and since I powered it up this morning it is no longer handling the graphics correctly - it's very low resolution - and the ethernet connection does not work at all. When I reboot into Windows 7, the ethernet and graphics work fine.

The ethernet controller is detected but it's not using it ?!

`lshw -C network` reports:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED 
    description: Network controller 
    product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) 
    vendor: Qualcomm Atheros physical 
    id: 0 bus 
    info: pci@0000:0c:00.0 
    version: 01 
    width: 64 bits 
    clock: 33MHz 
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list 
    configuration: latency=0 
    resources: memory:f69f0000-f69fffff *-network UNCLAIMED 
    description: Ethernet controller 
    product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller 
    vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. physical 
    id: 0 bus 
    info: pci@0000:09:00.0 
    version: 03 
    width: 64 bits 
    clock: 33MHz 
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list 
    configuration: latency=0 
    resources: ioport:ce00(size=256) memory:f0204000-f0204fff memory:f0200000-f0203fff memory:f0220000-f023ffff
```

The commands

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

and

```
/etc/init.d/networking force-reload
```

produce no output and have no apparent effect.

ifconfig shows only the loopback interface, no others.

The only new software I recall installing yesterday was the aspectj package. And the ethernet still worked fine after I installed it, until I power cycled.

Answer (score -1):

the problem is solved (mostly):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2244401&p=13122787#post13122787